# how to block a url in safari developer tools

Tags: safari

In the network tab of chrome devtools, if you right click on a resource there is an option to "block request URL". Does this exist in Safari developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist in safari developer tools.

But you could use parental controls to block certain hosts.

[image: Parental Controls]

Answer (score 0):

This feature still doesn't exist as of today but here is what I do:

I use [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), then I can block all the resources I need:

[image]